# Generate new variable conditioned on variable availability for 200 files at a time in R

Tags: r, if-statement

Generate new_var1 if the datafile has oldvar1 and not all observations are NA. Otherwise use oldvar2. to generate this new_var1. I am doing the following but for some cases it only selects the oldvar2 even though there is oldvar1. I need to select old_var1 if it exists and check if all values are missing. then if it passes that criteria I use old_var1. otherwise I use old_var2.

```
# creating the new variable 'new_var1'
 if ("oldvar1" %in% names(data)) {
     data$new_var1<- data$oldvar1
}
   if (anyNA(data$oldvar1)) {
     data$new_var1 <- data$oldvar2
   } else {
     data$new_var1<- data$oldvar1
   }
 } else {
   data$new_var1 <- data$oldvar2
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on R:

```
# Verify if oldvar1 exists and not all datapoints are NA
if ("oldvar1" %in% names(data) && !all(is.na(data$oldvar1))) {
  data$new_var1 <- data$oldvar1
} else {
  # Verify if oldvar2 exists and not all datapoints are NA
  if ("oldvar2" %in% names(data) && !all(is.na(data$oldvar2))) {
    data$new_var1 <- data$oldvar2
  } else {
    # Verify if hv121 exists and not all datapoints are NA
    if ("hv121" %in% names(data) && !all(is.na(data$hv121))) {
      data$new_var1 <- data$hv121
    } else {
      # If none of the above variables exist or all observations are NA, 
       #use hv110
      data$new_var1 <- data$hv110
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: mgdata! thats amazing please dont forget to choose my comment as the answer! have a great day